# Grayed out products that are not available

Tags: prestashop

I would like products that are not available on the listings to be displayed in a different color. Ideally, they would be gray or transparent to stand out from those available. How can I achieve this?

https://medpak.com.pl/suplementy-diety/

Comment: The main aim for SO is not to be a place where you can ask someone to do your job for free but to solve problems. Please tell what you tried, the error you got, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if product is not available then it wouldn't be show on the listing unless you set in prestashop panel that you allow to order unavailable products - but why then make them look different if I can still order them?

Anyway, to achieve your target:

1. Find inside your `product-list.tpl` line where is code for single product, and to the value of class for element `product-container` add a little code below to make it look like this:

   ```
   <div class="product-container {if $product.quantity <= 0}product-grayed{/if}">...</div>
   ```
2. Then in your css add:

   ```
   .product-grayed img {
       opacity: 0.5; // this code for transparent image
       filter: grayscale(100%); // this code for gray image
   }
   ```
3. Make any other css changes using added class `product-grayed`